# How to have more than 1 multiple choice dialogs in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: azure, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm building a simple automated response bot in azure bot framework for facebook messenger.

So far I have:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Welcome!");
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;

        if (message.Text.StartsWith("REPORT"))           

              PromptDialog.Choice(
                  context, 
                  this.OnOptionSelected, 
                  new List<string>() { "Good Driving", "Bad Driving"}, 
                  "Report Driver for?", 
                  "Not a valid option", 3);


        }            
        else
        {               
            await context.PostAsync($"Thank you for messaging AutoConscience! We will get back to you shortly <br/> <br/>You can report drivers on the road by replying with REPORT followed by the license plate"
                +"(REPORT ABC 123)");
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }


    public async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> argument)
    {
        var confirm = await argument;
        if (confirm == "Good Driving")
        {
            //Having Trouble with the following
                  PromptDialog.Choice(context, 
                  this.OnOptionSelected, 
                  new List<string>() { "Used Signal", "Allowed Lane Merge", "Kept Intersection Open", "Followed Right of Way","Patient Driver","Defensive Driver","Nice Car"}, 
                  "Report Driver for?", 
                  "Not a valid option", 3);
            //await context.PostAsync("Good");
        }
```

I want to show another multiple choice dialog after the first one but the bot fails after a user selects from the first dialog. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you are looping: on the second prompt the resume is "this.OnOptionSelected", which is the method from where you are launching the prompt

Comment: "I want to show another multiple choice dialog after the first one but the bot fails after a user selects from the first dialog" < what is failing? Add a capture / log

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently working on that. I'm testing on the Azure web chat tester only. Is there any way I can get logs from that? It just says the basic "Sorry my bot code is having issues"

Comment: Before you host your bot on Azure and configure facebook channel, do you try to test and debug your bot via Bot Framework Emulator on local? does your bot work as expected in Bot Framework Emulator?

Comment: I've actually made it work now. I called context.forward on the OnOptionSelected so that it forwards to another dialog. The problem was that I wasn't calling context.done on the other dialog so that it can go back to the parent dialog and call the resume function. 

My problem now although not related to this is that on FB, the bot does not reply to other users than me. 

Other than that, thanks for the replies!

Comment: `the bot does not reply to other users than me.` Please check if your app is published. In [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook#make-the-app-public-and-publish-the-page), you can find: *Until an app is published, it is in Development Mode. It will only work for admins, developers, and testers.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, to close a dialog and remove it from the stack (thereby sending the user back to the prior dialog in the stack), we should call `context.Done()`. We can find detailed information about **Dialog lifecycle** in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-manage-conversation-flow#dialog-lifecycle).

> My problem now although not related to this is that on FB, the bot does not reply to other users than me.

In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook#make-the-app-public-and-publish-the-page), we can know: *Until an app is published, it is in Development Mode. It will only work for admins, developers, and testers*.